# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'pack'

Tags: python, struct, module, runtime-error

```
import struct

f = open('file.bin', 'wb')
value = 1.23456
data = struct.pack("f", value)
f.write(data)
f.close()

f = open('file.bin', 'rb')
print struct.unpack('f',f.read(4))
f.close()
```

I try and perform the above code and it gives me the error:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'pack'

I am using python 2.7.5 and I have checked the module list and "struct" is there.

Comment: Your code works for me. Daniel Roseman's answer is probably accurate.

Comment: I have the same error and dont have a file named struct.py at all (did a `find . -name struct.py` to be sure)

Comment: to answer above, check your PYTHONPATH, LD_LIBRARY_PATH, and PATH

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have a file in your local directory called struct.py, which is shadowing the standard library version.

Comment: And don't forget to delete the .pyc files